# CSCart Htaccess and directory php file

Tags: .htaccess, cs-cart

I have a cscart installation, with the classic htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(win) [NC]
RewriteRule . index.php?sef_rewrite=1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But, there is a folder with a php script I need to be accessible. Anytime I try to access that script, it shows CScart 404 page. But if change the script in the subdirectory to any other different file extension, it suddenly works.

cscart.com/folder/file.php   **doesn't work**

cscart.com/folder/file.html  **works**

Would any of you guys know how to turn htacess for that folder to run and show cscart 404 page?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if under folder **cscart.com/folder/** is present any **.htaccess**, this may be the issue

Some cs-cart folder have **.htaccess** with content

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files ~ "\.(js|css|png|jpg|gz)$">
  order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Or correct the path when moving the CS-Cart to another directory.

```
 RewriteBase /some/other/path
```